# What is the standard common mode voltage of Media Dependent Interface MDI[0:3]± signals?

Tags: voltage, common-mode, lvds, phy, sgmii

I am working on the selection RJ45 connector for MDI interface between PHY and the link-partner.
I am planning to use [this PHY](https://www.marvell.com/content/dam/marvell/en/public-collateral/transceivers/marvell-phys-transceivers-alaska-88e1111-datasheet.pdf) for my SGMII interface application. From various online readings, I understood some RJ45 connectors can have CT (Center tap) pin connection to a power supply to bias MDI signals. I just want to clarify if I have to select RJ45 connector with CT power supply to bias the MDI signals?

For the RJ45 connector selection, I would like to know what is the common-mode voltage of MDI signals (which I could not find in the [datasheet](https://www.marvell.com/content/dam/marvell/en/public-collateral/transceivers/marvell-phys-transceivers-alaska-88e1111-datasheet.pdf)). Is MDI signal common-mode voltage a standard value or it will change based on the selected PHY?

Comment: The datasheet says to refer to the hardware docs for the device. There’s probably specific layout and bypass requirements as well so you’ll need to refer to that document.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are not looking only for a connector, as plain connectors don't have a center tap cannot be directly connected to an Ethernet PHY. You always need isolation transformers, whether as a separate component, or built-in to the connector housing, and these components are better known as MagJacks. And it is the parameters of these transformers that are important and thus suitable components are found by reading the hardware design guide, which does not seem to be freely downloadable from the manufacturer website. If you can't find manufacturer example, you can't design with it.